# Easiest way to have a MySql database to make some queries against a dump file

Tags: mysql

I have a dump file of a MySql Database (I never worked with MySql, but I am assuming it's similar enough to SQL Server), because I don't want to run my queries in production.

I never created a local environment and I never worked with MySql. I tried to download MySql Workbench, but the GUI is not helping me. In SQL Server I would just connect with localhost and then everything would be fine. It was back then I had a managed PC by my previous organization. I suppose they installed everything to me.

I want to set up it and just go away. It could be in the cloud or locally.

Comment: This can get real complicated real quick, without knowing your OS or skill level.. probably best to use docker containers for a local testbed. There are loads of tutorials to set up docker and launch a mysql (or mariadb) container. For a user interface I usually go for DBeaver. For a better answer: What OS are you on? Are you comfortable with using containers? Do you have experience with AWS/Azure?

Comment: I understand your question, but it isn't really a good fit for Stack Overflow. This site wants questions to be about specific code problems, not basics of installing and using software. There is already documentation on [installing MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/installing.html) on various platforms, and [tutorials for common tasks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tutorial.html). As your question is written, it would require someone to basically type in those documents to answer you. I suggest you go do some reading first.

Comment: If you have more specific questions after trying to follow the docs, it'd be better to ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com unless the question is about code.